# currently unsure of how to fix this error involving sqline3 python

Tags: python

```
  total = cur.fetchone()[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

```
import sqlite3

def display_records(results):
    for row in results:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    print()



def display_total(total):
    for row in total:
        print(row[2])
    print()



conn = sqlite3.connect('cities.db')

cur = conn.cursor()


x = int(input('Please select a choice by entering the corresponding number: '))


if x == 1:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by population, in ascending order.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY Population''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)


elif x == 2:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by population, in descending order.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY Population DESC''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)

elif x == 3:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by name.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY CityName''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)

elif x == 4:
    print('Displaying the total population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT sum(Population) FROM Cities''')
    total = cur.fetchone()[2]

elif x == 5:
    print('Displaying the average population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT AVG(Population) FROM Cities''')
    avg = cur.fetchone()[2]
    print('The total population is:', format(avg, '.2f'))







conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Im trying to write a program that connects to a database. I have it connected and the other fetchall functions work fine. however the fetchone function is giving me a problem even tho I have entered the correct row. It would be great if someone could shoot me some pointers. :)

Comment: For x equal to 4 or 5 the SQL queries only produce a single row with a **single column** due to the "SELECT"ed result.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about fixing it then? also x = 4 and 5 is just so the user can select an option to be displayed

Comment: Assign `cur.fetchone()[0]` to "total" or "avg" respectively.